# Angular having controllers and services in different files

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers and one service in my angular app splitted in 3 different files as follows:

**Main controller**

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("mainController", function(){
    console.log("Hi main controller");
})
```

**Second controller**

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.controller("secondController", ['myCoolService', function($rootScope, myCoolService){
    console.log("Hi second controller")
}]);
```

**Service**

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.service('myCoolService', function() {
});
```

I've made sure I was importing it correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/myCoolService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/secondController.js"></script>
```

However I'm getting an unknown service exception:

```
Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myCoolService
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: may be issue with something written in myCoolService.js

Comment: When you use `angular.module("app")` (note without `[ ]' angular will retrieve the module, not create a new one)

Comment: post code inside ur service..issue should be in service js file ..may be u havent included angular-resource.js file

Comment: Yes, I saw it. That's why I deleted my comment ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.controller("secondController", ['$rootScope', 'myCoolService', 
  function($rootScope, myCoolService){
    console.log("Hi second controller")
  }
]);
```

See, AngularJS injector either gets names of specific dependencies from an array - or uses factory function arguments for them. The first way is actually recommended, as it withstands minification and lets Angular skip parsing the function's argument list.

The point is, AngularJS won't mix those approaches: if list of deps is specified, it IS used, and any hints given by arguments are just ignored. That's why your original code actually puts `myCoolService` into $rootScope variable (the first dependency is assigned to the first argument), but just doesn't know where to find the second one.

Comment: How's myCoolService defined then? Please add its declaration into the question.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I had an error in my service. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your second controller you are missing dependency.

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.controller("secondController", ['$rootScope', 'myCoolService', function($rootScope, myCoolService){
    console.log("Hi second controller")
}]);
```